# Sentinel::check() always return false after redirect from login method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using Sentinel with Laravel 5.3 .

Inside the login method

`Sentinel::authenticate($credentials)`

works fine and each time i get user object from `Sentinel::check()` after successful login.

But problem arise after redirect, and `Sentinel::check()` showing false inside the `route, middle-ware, views`. Any idea about the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake by me. I extend each of the sentinel model in my codebase due to implement `Uuids`. But mistake arise due to wrong inheritance and it was `class QuitchPersistence extends EloquentActivation` instead of `class QuitchPersistence extends EloquentPersistence`. Now it's working fine.